# How to install a wireless driver on my dell mini 9 running ubuntu 12.10 off a usb?

Tags: usb, 12.10, gnome-terminal, dell-mini-9

Not sure how to install a driver and which driver to use - or whether I could do something in terminal. I'm pretty sure there's no driver there already but I might be wrong. I'm running a dell mini 910 inspiron off of a 32gb usb with ubuntu 12.10 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I go to System Settings, open up Software Sources, go to end tab Other Sources and there is where I turn on the Broadcom wireless card.

Hope it works for you cause that's how I turn mine on running from USB.